# Php.ini: Local Value vs Master Value (safe_mode, specifically)

Tags: php.ini

I can change php.ini values on my Apache and restart to see them in effect via a script showing `php_info()`. However, one setting is causing problems: safe_mode. I set it to "off" in php.ini but `php_info()` still shows it as

```
Local value: On
Master value: Off
```

How can I find out which local value is overriding the master value? There's no htaccess directive of that kind in the httpdocs folder in question...

(I already downloaded all files `php_info()` claims to be additional .ini files parsed, but safe_mode is not set in them.)

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer now. The value is overridden via a Plesk setting, which I can change by going to Plesk -> the domain in question -> Setup, and then adjusting the PHP safe mode option.